# Converting Base64 encoded tab delimited file in PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I am writing a reporting app that needs to consume logs which have been stored in the DB as base 64 encoded strings. I am able to decode them no problem, however, I am having some trouble getting them to be fed into str_getcsv() properly.

Below is the data I am working with, the code and the outputs. It seems to me that once decoded the files are not recognizable as tab-delimited. However, if I decode it with this URL and and save as a text file, I can open it properly in excel.

https://www.base64decode.org/

In PHP however, it seems to be an issue with recognizing some of the tabs and the line breaks seem to completely go away. I think it has to do with the encoding,  the DB table and column are both UTF-8. They are being recognized as ASCII - which is a subset of UTF-8, but I am not sure if they need to be explicitly UTF-8 for it to work (the site that works uses UTF-8).

The code: very simple (though at this point I may be going overboard with the encoding)

```
            // get the stored result (laravel eloquent)
        $media_result = MediaResult::where("video_id", "=", $media_benchmark->id)->firstOrFail();


        # decode the access_log stored as b64 string
        $tab_file = base64_decode(mb_convert_encoding($media_result->access_log, "UTF-8"));

        $encoding =  mb_detect_encoding($tab_file); // I was using iconv() so I grabbed this - it is always ASCII

        $new_file = mb_convert_encoding($tab_file,'UTF-8');

        $encoding_new =  mb_detect_encoding($new_file);

        #if I were to echo both encoding variables, it would be ASCII - no matter what I do.


        # convert the supposed tab-delimited file into an array
        $full_stats = str_getcsv($new_file, 0, "\t");
```

Here is a sample base64 encoded log:

```
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
```

Here is the same string decoded:

```
URI serverAddress   numberOfServerAddressChanges    mediaRequestsWWAN   transferDuration    numberOfBytesTransferred    numberOfMediaRequests   playbackStartDate   playbackSessionID   playbackStartOffset playbackType startupTime    durationWatched numberOfDroppedVideoFrames  numberOfStalls  numberOfSegmentsDownloaded  segmentsDownloadedDuration  downloadOverdue observedBitrateStandardDeviation    observedMaxBitrate observedMinBitrate   switchBitrate   indicatedBitrate    observedBitrate http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/01/prog_index.m3u8    8.254.23.254    0   0   0.678280709 1099612 3   2016-05-10 19:21:18 +0000   7A1290DC-1630-49FC-AA64-CC76C181C72A    42  LIVE    0.2532979846000671  16.08326596021652   0   0   3   18  0   -1  25572901.38330787   18207987.3285259    10115548.78381825   492000  21025955.05388924 http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/06/prog_index.m3u8  8.253.32.126    8   0   35.740163622    123481972   43  2016-05-10 19:21:34 +0000   7A1290DC-1630-49FC-AA64-CC76C181C72A    58.028994358    LIVE    0   241.9269759654999   0   0 43    258 0   -1  46885903.03598993   10807457.38240667   -1  4000000 31782360.61452863
```

Finally, here is the resulting array:

```
Array ( [0] => URI  serverAddress   numberOfServerAddressChanges    mediaRequestsWWAN   transferDuration    numberOfBytesTransferred    numberOfMediaRequests   playbackStartDate   playbackSessionID   playbackStartOffset playbackType    startupTime durationWatched numberOfDroppedVideoFrames  numberOfStalls  numberOfSegmentsDownloaded  segmentsDownloadedDuration  downloadOverdue observedBitrateStandardDeviation observedMaxBitrate observedMinBitrate  switchBitrate   indicatedBitrate    observedBitrate http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/ [1] => 1/prog_index.m3u8 8.254.23.254    [2] => 0 [3] => .67828 [4] => 7 [5] => 9    1 [6] => 99612  3   2 [7] => 16- [8] => 5-1 [9] => 19:21:18 + [10] => [11] => [12] => [13] => 7A1290DC-1630-49FC-AA64-CC76C181C72A42    LIVE    [14] => .2532979846 [15] => [16] => [17] => 671 16. [18] => 8326596 [19] => 21652   [20] => 03  18  [21] => -1255729 [22] => 1.3833 [23] => 787 182 [24] => 7987.3285259    1 [25] => 115548.78381825   492 [26] => [27] => [28] => 21025955.05388924 http://vevoplaylist-live.hls.adaptive.level3.net/vevo/ch1/06/prog_index.m3u88.253.32.126  8   [29] => 35.740163622123481972   43  2 [30] => 16- [31] => 5-1 [32] => 19:21:34 + [33] => [34] => [35] => [36] => 7A1290DC-1630-49FC-AA64-CC76C181C72A58. [37] => 28994358   LIVE    [38] => 241.9269759654999 [39] => 043   258 [40] => -1468859 [41] => 3. [42] => 3598993 1 [43] => 8 [44] => 7457.3824 [45] => 667   -1  4 [46] => [47] => [48] => [49] => [50] => [51] => 31782360.61452863 )
```

Comment: Base64 is always pure ASCII-7, and by consequence also UTF-8, because ASCII-7 is a subset of UTF-8. When I decode the base64 log you provided, I **do** get the line-breaks. See https://eval.in/568911

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep in mind that `str_getcsv()`

- parses only **one** line of a csv file
- expects the delimiter "\t" to be the **second** parameter, not the third

You probably want something like:

```
$full_stats = [];
foreach(explode("\n", $decoded) as $line) {
    $full_stats[] = str_getcsv($line, "\t");
}
var_dump($full_stats);
```

This will output an array containing 3 arrays (aka rows) containing 24 items (aka columns) each.

See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1ccf5115df6f8c342ff7c7e451f3ea26e081197e for working example and generated output.

Regarding the import of data that contains line breaks you should switch to fget_csv() which handles line breaks correctly:

```
$csv = <<< eot
"first","my data
with line breaks"
"second", "simple data"
eot;

// We need to "convert" the string to a file handle
$fp = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $csv,'r');
while ($data = fgetcsv($fp)) {
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Comment: d'oh, believe it or not 10 years of php and I have never used that function, i was confusing it with fgetcsv(); thx

Comment: What happen if I have a column with two paragraphs? Its breaking these two paragraphs into two lines. How could i fix it?

Comment: @JeanHoffmann use fget_csv() instead of str_getcsv(), see update of my solution above